# Handle special symbols using PHP (i.e. ™ instead of â„¢)

Tags: php

I'm trying to read an XML document which contains `&#x2122;` (™), but for some reason, no matter what I try, it always displays as â„¢.

For example:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<item><title>test</title></item><item><title>&#x2122;</title></item>');
foreach ($xml->item AS $item)
{
    echo $item->title . "<br />";
}

Results in:
test
â„¢
```

Just to be clear, I don't want it to just show appropriately, I need to insert it to a DB.

Thanks!

Comment: And what exactly have you tried? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in your original post works fine for me, at least if I add `<xml>` tags. Make sure the content encoding of your HTML page is set correctly, i.e. send the HTTP header `Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8` or set this in your `<head>`. When inserting the string containing this symbol into the database, first set the character set to UTF-8 using `SET NAMES UTF8`. Of course, the database/table/field into which you are inserting should be set to UTF8 too.

Comment: The content encoding doesn't have anything to do with this issue actually, as the value inserted into the DB is corrupted (and this isn't a database issue, it works fine if I try to insert the symbol manually), so there is something wrong with the way the parser reads the XML I guess.

Comment: Then you'll have to show us the code you use to insert this into the database, because the code you've shown above works perfectly for me :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using utf8_decode or utf8_encode php functions. They should convert it into the correct character.

```
echo utf8_decode($this->title);
```

Comment: This should work too, but in this day and age it would probably be a good idea to design for UTF-8 compliance :)

Answer (score 0):

Run htmlentities() over the whole string before you load it into simplexmlelement. This will convert anything PHP recognises as a html entity (e.g. £, &, €). This will let you store them in your database without havin to use all the mb* functions, and all the other hoops you need to jump through for UTF8 support in databases.

If you have any *really* special characters that can not be encoded this way, this will not work.

Answer (score -1):

If php is getting it from the XML file correctly, and the problem is outputting it into your database, use [`htmlspecialchars`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php), which will convert all symbols into their html equivalents. The symbol will be stored as "™", which can be handled well when you retrieve it from the database.

Comment: htmlspecialchars doesn't seem to work. When I echo the text it displays as â„¢, and the only way I can get it to display (and only display) correctly is by sending a content type utf-8 header.

Comment: Hm, php may not be reading from the XML file correctly. Can you post the code you're using?

Comment: You need to use 'htmlentities' instead of htmlspecialchars.